# Persistent USB synced to my laptop

Tags: 16.04, live-usb, backup

I apologize if this is a duplicate, don't even know the right words to search.

What inspired the thought:I know I can backup to a USB. I also know that a USB can be a persistent(believe this means it saves data between sessions) OS.

I currently run UBUNTU 16.04. I love the speed of my SSD as well as the performance of how it is setup as a standard install, plus I don't have to worry about breaking the USB with it in a laptop all the time. However the idea of throwing that in my pocket and having MY software setup available when I get where I am going sounds amazing.

Is it possible to take the OS as it sits on my hard-drive and use that to create a portable OS? This way i have all my programs and files every time I leave the house and all I need is my flash-drive. This way I don't have to mess with windows period anymore, however being able to go to a friends and use his hardware setup with my software setup and not having to plug and unplug sounds amazing. Even if the USB cant back transfer this would be amazing. It sounds kind of far fetched to me, however the *nix community never fails to amaze me at what they can/have do(ne).

Comment: So I just did some work with ubuntu mate for pi wondering if this could be useful? just trying to start a dialogue

Comment: I somewhat get the idea, but I don't think I fully understand all. Host system to USB synced? Possible. With persistence? Possible. Autodetect any hardware? I think this is for live CD/USB only, and not for persistent/full install. Because of my vague knowledge, I could neither answer nor upvote this post.

Answer (score -1):

This will work if your back-up is under 8 GB.
I think its persistant and if not use Unetbootin to make a fresh persistant drive. I noticed that Ubuntu 16.04's built in Start-up disk creator still has a glitch the last time I tried to use it (I had to create an ISO folder and load the .iso from it. I thought it would work but it refused to load Ubuntu from the persistent usb.)

*sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nemh/systemback

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install systemback*